# JavaScript for loop to set attribute

Tags: javascript

1. I have several `<input>` tags. I want to change the type to number if it is `type="text"`,so I make a loop function but that doesn't work and no error appears.

   (I don't know how to make it change from `<input type="text">` to `<input type="number">` when I load this page because there are many tags so I think it's fast to use `for` loop )

   ```
   var a=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].getAttribute("type");
   function setvalue(){
       for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
           var b=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i]
           if (a="text"){
               b.setAttribute("text","number");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. I have several `<select>` tags in other page, which looks like `<select id="inp_015"> <select id="inp_025">... <select id="inp_105">..<select id="inp_205">` the last number is 5 and the front is from 01 to 20)
   I want to change its width. I made some code below but also don't work.

   ```
   for(i=0;i<3;i++){
       for(i=1;y<10;i++){
           document.getElementById("inp_"+"i"+"y"+"5").style.width="125px";
       }
   }
   ```

---

editted

```
function setwidth(){
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(y=1;y<10;i++){
    document.getElementById("inp_"+i+y+"5").style.width="125px";
}}}
```

(My script was put at the bottom of the body tag)
I hope I can get to know which part went wrong.

Comment: `"inp_"+"i"+"y"+"5"` should be `"inp_"+i+y+"5")`

Comment: thanks,if I want to automatic change the width how should I do

Comment: Can you use jQuery?  `$('input[type="text"]').attr('type', 'number')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working through your code:

Line 1: `var a=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].getAttribute("type");`

At this point `i` is `undefined`.  So you get the list of all elements with tag "input", then get one element from the list and get the value of that one element's "type" attribute.  This probably throws an exception because with an undefined index you'll get an undefined value that does not have a method getAttribute().  Even if it weren't undefined, you want to process all the elements, not just one string.

Line 2: `function setvalue(){
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        var b=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i]
        if (a="text"){
            b.setAttribute("text","number");
        }
    }
}`

You define a function.  Actually, due to hoisting, the function is defined first.  But this function is never called in the code you show.

Let's review the function anyway.

`for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){`

This looks okay, except that `a` is a string, not the array of elements you want to process.

`var b=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i]`

This is functional so far as getting an element goes, however it is inefficient because each time through the loop you make a new array containing all the elements.

`if (a="text"){`

Here you check if value of the "type" attribute of the (undefined) element you retrieved on Line 1 is text.  This does not relate to the element this iteration of the loop should be processing.

`b.setAttribute("text","number");`

You create a new attribute named "text" and set it to "number".  This does not set the "type" attribute.

Your code can be fixed, though I would suggest that jQuery makes this task much simpler:  `$('input[type="text"]').attr('type', 'number')`

Comment: If I want this to automatic be execute should I put it in window.onload{}?

Comment: Using jQuery I put it in a "document ready" callback. I have not looked into browser compatibility for the native events.  In jQuery this looks like `$(document).ready( setvalue );`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the context of your code, but it looks all mixed up. Here's what it looks like you're trying to do, with some comments.

```
function setvalue(){
    var a=document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //moved inside function, returns array
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){ //loop through array
        var b=a[i]; //element in array
        var c = b.getAttribute("type");//get type attribute of element
        if (c == "text"){ //changed "=" (assignment operator) to "==" (comparison operator)
            b.setAttribute("type","number"); //changed "text" to "type"
        }
    }
}
```